# writing grok expression for name value pairs

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have the below output from metrics.

```
05 Feb 2018 16:02:37,076  INFO SaveMetrics:29 - Metrics  :[Metric [name=httpsessions.max, value=-1, timestamp=Mon Feb 05 16:02:37 EST 2018], Metric [name=httpsessions.active, value=0, timestamp=Mon Feb 05 16:02:37 EST 2018]]
05 Feb 2018 16:02:37,085  INFO SaveMetrics:29 - Metrics  :[Metric [name=datasource.primary.active, value=0, timestamp=Mon Feb 05 16:02:37 EST 2018], Metric [name=datasource.primary.usage, value=0.0, timestamp=Mon Feb 05 16:02:37 EST 2018], Metric [name=datasource.hcarsessioninfo.active, value=0, timestamp=Mon Feb 05 16:02:37 EST 2018], Metric [name=datasource.hcarsessioninfo.usage, value=0.0, timestamp=Mon Feb 05 16:02:37 EST 2018], Metric [name=datasource.vhcpdemo.active, value=0, timestamp=Mon Feb 05 16:02:37 EST 2018], Metric [name=datasource.vhcpdemo.usage, value=0.0, timestamp=Mon Feb 05 16:02:37 EST 2018]]
05 Feb 2018 16:02:37,086  INFO SaveMetrics:29 - Metrics  :[Metric [name=mem, value=854991, timestamp=Mon Feb 05 16:02:37 EST 2018], Metric [name=mem.free, value=441374, timestamp=Mon Feb 05 16:02:37 EST 2018], Metric [name=processors, value=8, timestamp=Mon Feb 05 16:02:37 EST 2018], Metric [name=instance.uptime, value=2520, timestamp=Mon Feb 05 16:02:37 EST 2018], Metric [name=uptime, value=78701, timestamp=Mon Feb 05 16:02:37 EST 2018], Metric [name=systemload.average, value=-1.0, timestamp=Mon Feb 05 16:02:37 EST 2018], Metric [name=heap.committed, value=733184, timestamp=Mon Feb 05 16:02:37 EST 2018], Metric [name=heap.init, value=262144, timestamp=Mon Feb 05 16:02:37 EST 2018], Metric [name=heap.used, value=291809, timestamp=Mon Feb 05 16:02:37 EST 2018], Metric [name=heap, value=3708416, timestamp=Mon Feb 05 16:02:37 EST 2018], Metric [name=nonheap.committed, value=124120, timestamp=Mon Feb 05 16:02:37 EST 2018], Metric [name=nonheap.init, value=2496, timestamp=Mon Feb 05 16:02:37 EST 2018], Metric [name=nonheap.used, value=121807, timestamp=Mon Feb 05 16:02:37 EST 2018], Metric [name=nonheap, value=0, timestamp=Mon Feb 05 16:02:37 EST 2018], Metric [name=threads.peak, value=77, timestamp=Mon Feb 05 16:02:37 EST 2018], Metric [name=threads.daemon, value=13, timestamp=Mon Feb 05 16:02:37 EST 2018], Metric [name=threads.totalStarted, value=97, timestamp=Mon Feb 05 16:02:37 EST 2018], Metric [name=threads, value=77, timestamp=Mon Feb 05 16:02:37 EST 2018], Metric [name=classes, value=13851, timestamp=Mon Feb 05 16:02:37 EST 2018], Metric [name=classes.loaded, value=13851, timestamp=Mon Feb 05 16:02:37 EST 2018], Metric [name=classes.unloaded, value=0, timestamp=Mon Feb 05 16:02:37 EST 2018], Metric [name=gc.ps_scavenge.count, value=11, timestamp=Mon Feb 05 16:02:37 EST 2018], Metric [name=gc.ps_scavenge.time, value=466, timestamp=Mon Feb 05 16:02:37 EST 2018], Metric [name=gc.ps_marksweep.count, value=3, timestamp=Mon Feb 05 16:02:37 EST 2018], Metric [name=gc.ps_marksweep.time, value=459, timestamp=Mon Feb 05 16:02:37 EST 2018]]
```

I need to write grok expression for extracting each name value pairs.

Is there any way of doing this?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: use the KV filter: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html

Comment: @pandaadb Since there's more than one set of key-value pair per line, I don't think the kv filter can be applied directly. A first step, splitting the metrics would be necessary before using the kv filter.

Comment: Yes. You could use any filter that fits to extract the kv-pairs out, and then use the filter on the output of that.

Comment: Or you can directly use the kv filter if you don't mind having all the values from the same key together (for example, the first line for `name` would give: `"name":["httpsessions.max,","httpsessions.active,"]`)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use grok for this purpose.

Writing your own filter might be an alternative.

So you can parse each event and properly convert it to a hash.

You can write inline ruby filter as a starting point.

https://regexr.com/ might help debugging your regex expressions.

### **Resources**

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/_how_to_write_a_logstash_filter_plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

Considering the complexity of what I've done, I think logstash is the wrong tool for the job and you would be better served by a real program (or a custom ruby filter), but since I got a working solution, I'll post it.

It might be possible to use the split and kv filter like this:

```
# extract the part that interest us
grok {
    match => {
        "message" => "%{GREEDYDATA}Metrics  :\[%{GREEDYDATA:Metrics}\]"
    }
}

# divide each event in multiple events, depending on the contents of the Metrics field
split {
    field => "Metrics"
    terminator => "], Metric ["
    target => "metric"
}

# removing things left behind when splitting the Metrics field.
mutate {
    gsub => ["metric", "Metric \[", "",
             "metric", "\]", ""]
}

# apply the kv filter, extracting key-value pairs from the metric field
kv { 
    source => "metric"
    field_split => ","
}
```

For example, the result for the first line would be:

```
{  
   " timestamp":"Mon Feb 05 16:02:37 EST 2018",
   "@timestamp":"2018-02-07T15:01:58.609Z",
   "metric":"name=httpsessions.max, value=-1, timestamp=Mon Feb 05 16:02:37 EST 2018",
   " value":"-1",
   "@version":"1",
   "name":"httpsessions.max"
}
{  
   " timestamp":"Mon Feb 05 16:02:37 EST 2018",
   "@timestamp":"2018-02-07T15:01:58.609Z",
   "metric":"name=httpsessions.active, value=0, timestamp=Mon Feb 05 16:02:37 EST 2018",
   " value":"0",
   "@version":"1",
   "name":"httpsessions.active"
}
```

I've removed the `message`, `host` and `Metrics` fields (with `mutate{ remove_field => ["Metrics", "message", "host"]}`) in order for it to be readable.